# How to align a button into the bottom right corner in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm extremely new to JavaFX, and I'm attempting to get a button(specifically `scrapeBtn`) into the bottom right corner of an application.  Here is what I have so far:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Driver extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button scrapeBtn = new Button();
        scrapeBtn.setText("Scrape!");
        scrapeBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Scrape button pressed.");
            }
        });

        TextField console = new TextField();

        GridPane root = new GridPane();    

        GridPane.setConstraints(scrapeBtn, 2, 2, 1, 1);
        root.getChildren().add(scrapeBtn);

        root.getChildren().add(console);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Wiki Scraper");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this?  Some tips in general to aligning and formatting things with JavaFX would also be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How to get the button into the lower-right corner will depend greatly upon which layout container you choose, and it sounds like you aren't entirely committed to `GridPane` yet, and that you need to take a tour of all the layout containers available.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html) is a logical place to start.

Comment: If you just want to stick your button to the bottom, better go with AnchorPane instead of a GridPane

Comment: You may also find it easier to use SceneBuilder: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

Answer (score 8):

I often use a `BorderPane` for similar purposes (e.g. a Dialog with some text and controls etc. at the center and one or more buttons at the bottom). Therefore, I use the `BorderPane` as root and a `HBox` as "button container" at the bottom. Finally, I set the botton alignment to "RIGHT".

Here an example based on your code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // center
    VBox vbCenter = new VBox(); // use any container as center pane e.g. VBox
    TextField console = new TextField();
    vbCenter.getChildren().add(console);

    // bottom respectively "button area"
    HBox hbButtons = new HBox();
    Button scrapeBtn = new Button();
    scrapeBtn.setText("Scrape!");
    scrapeBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Scrape button pressed.");
      }
    });
    hbButtons.getChildren().add(scrapeBtn);
    hbButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    // root
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20)); // space between elements and window border
    root.setCenter(vbCenter);
    root.setBottom(hbButtons);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Wiki Scraper");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This code leads to this (after resizing the window a little bit):

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use two BorderPanes to place a control bottom right

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    BorderPane bottom = new BorderPane();
    bottom.setRight(new Button("I am placed bottom right"));
    root.setBottom(bottom);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setHeight(400);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image]